# Функциональное тестирование cli приложенией на php что для этого есть?

Tags: php, phpunit

у меня есть некоторое консольное приложение на php 
Мне необходимо провести функциональное тестирование. 
Подскажите какие решения есть для этого? - для модульных тестов вроде как есть phpunit 
Но как быть с функциональным тестированием?

Answer (score 0):

Однозначно [Codeception](https://codeception.com/docs/04-FunctionalTests)
Extended для тестов